# Showing a local RSS Feed on my app?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, rss

So i'm using phonegap build with, html5 jqm and javascript and css obviously.

i have a local rss feed in xml format that has been made and will be updated with new events etc.

i want the RSS feed to show like a list basically at the moment i'm no bothered with anything fancy look as i've not even managed to get it to show up, all my efforts have been futile.

Any answers accepted. For practicality lets call the feed rss.xml.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [jfeed](http://hovinne.com/articles/jfeed-jquery-rss-atom-feed-parser-plugin/), for example

```
jQuery.getFeed({
    url: 'rss.xml',
    success: function(feed) {
        console,log(feed.title);
    }
});
```

Also, you can use [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), here is an example for [PhoneGap](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/10/11/PhoneGap-RSS-Reader) and [an article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-an-rss-reader-with-jquery-mobile-2/) worth reading.

Comment: i thought jfeed was outdated now? i think i read somewhere it doesn't work with newer versions as it hasn't been updated for 2 years. The article uses php which sadly i cannot use in phonegap build. However the $.get and phonegap links seems quite good so i'm going to try the latter first. As a novice it may take sometime!

Comment: The example for phonegap got it working! Thanks man.